# How to run Office 2003 and 2007 on the same computer?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2003

I installed Microsoft Office 2003 and 2007 together on a Windows XP Machine

When I launch Word 2003 or 2007 a setup tries to reconfigure my system

How can I Fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How to get rid of the installer / configuration dialog when running Office 2007 and Office 2003 on the same system - for Vista and other versions of Windows**

The fix to the problem is very simple as it turns out - simply run the following commands (by pressing the Windows Key+R or typing it into the Start/Run command box.  Use the line with Office\11.0 if you have Office 2003 installed and Office\12.0 if you have Office 2007 installed.  You can use both if you have both installed :

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Word\Options /v NoReReg /t REG_DWORD /d 1

reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Options /v NoReReg /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

That is it.  Office 2007 might want to have one more spin round the block with it's configuration dialog box, but that should be it.

*[Source](http://uksbsguy.com/blogs/doverton/archive/2007/07/21/how-to-get-rid-of-the-installer-configuration-dialog-when-running-office-2007-and-office-2003-on-the-same-system-for-vista-and-other-versions-of-windows.aspx)*